# how can I get URI of currently dispatched web resource, in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

How can I get a full URI of the resource currently dispatched in JAX-RS? I'm trying to return a URI of newly created object, and need a prefix part of it, with host, port, etc.:

```
// @import-s skipped
public class Factory {
  @POST
  public final Response create() {
    Integer id;
    // new object created and id is set
    return Response.created(
      URI.create(prefix + "/object/" + id)
    ).build();
  }
}
```

Where can I get this `prefix` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to inject `UriInfo`:

`public final Response create(@Context UriInfo info) {...}`

At that point, you can either use `info` directly or get a `UriBuilder` from one of its `get*Builder` methods.